# How to connect to a wifi

Tags: wireless

So I'm really new and i have no idea how to connect the ubuntu server to a wifi. After command: lsusb i got these results:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2357:0109 TP-Link TL WN823N RTL8192EU
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Can you get a temporary ethernet connection? Is the wifi USB, PCI or some other? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: i could get a ethernet connection but i don't want it connected to a ethernet 24/7, because my wifi is far away and it would just get in way

Comment: I need one more piece of information before I propose an answer. If your wireless device is internal, likely PCI, please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` If USB, then: `lsusb`.

Comment: done, could you also help me with connecting to the server from a diffrent wifi or should i ask another question?

Answer (score 0):

Your device  2357:0109 TP-Link TL WN823N RTL8192EU is covered by the driver rtl8xxxu that’s included in recent Ubuntu versions. Please confirm:

```
modinfo rtl8xxxu | grep 0109
```

If you get this output, then your device has a driver already installed:

```
alias:          usb:v2357p0109d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
```

Find out what the interface name is:

```
ip addr show
```

The interface name will be something like wlx12457803 or some such. Please make a carefully proofread note of the interface name. Also note the ethernet name. It will be something like enp0s25 or similar.

Next, with a temporary ethernet connection, get an internet connection:

```
sudo dhclient enp0s25
```

Of course, substitute your ethernet interface name, if not enp0s25.

Once you have a connection, install some prerequitites:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install wireless-tools wpasupplicant
```

In Ubuntu server installation, networking is handled in netplan. Please amend your netplan file thus:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/*.yaml
```

Change the file to read:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlx12457830:
      dhcp4: yes
      access-points:
        "network_ssid_name":
          password: "**********"
```

Of course, substitute your interface name.

Please note that the access point name and password are enclosed in quotation marks ". Also, netplan is very specific as to indentation and spacing. Please proofread carefully.

Save (Ctrl+o) and exit (Ctrl+x) the text editor nano.

After saving the file, please do:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Reboot. Check to see if you connected. Do you have an IP address?

```
ip addr show
```

Are you connected?

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```